Updating comonad with tensor product with R-module
I am working with a comonad $C$ on the category of $R$-modules, $C\colon\mathbf{R\text{-}Mod}\to \mathbf{R\text{-}Mod}$, which arises from the free-forget adjunction $F \dashv U\colon \mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{R\text{-}Mod}$, so that C = FU
I am interested in constructing a new comonad that operates on $\mathbf{S\text{-}Mod}$ (the category of $S$-modules for some ring $S$) by taking the tensor product of this comonad $C$ with an $R$-module $S$. In other words, I would like to understand how to construct and work with the comonad $S \otimes_R C\colon \mathbf{S\text{-}Mod} \to \mathbf{S\text{-}Mod}$ in the category of $S$-modules.
Tensor Product Construction: How can the tensor product $S \otimes C$ be formally defined as a comonad on $\mathbf{S\text{-}Mod}$? Is there a standard way to construct such a tensor product in this categorical context?

You mean $FU$? Isn't $UF$ the monad on $\text{Set}$?

You are right, fixed.
